# What files do I need to host an angularJS website

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, web-hosting, bower, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm trying to host my first website. I've made it using angularjs, bootstrap and yeoman as a generator. However when I tried to upload it, I realized that the full size of everything in my folder (including the generated stuff by yeoman) was nearly 100mb.

What files do I actually need to host? Node is nearly 60mb and grunt isn't much smaller. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the main html files and all its dependent js and css files

Comment: Right - if you're jusing the angular-generator, the files you need for hosting are the content of the `app/` folder.

Comment: naeramarth, no thats wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a web server like nginx or apache already on that server, you just need to upload the `dist` folder that is created when you run `grunt build`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that generator and node stuff just to host a simple test project.

What you actually need is a single HTML file, called `index.html`. Include Angular and bootstrap (you can omit this, too, if you can go without fancy styles) and create a file `app.js` which will hold your application logic.

http://angularjs.org shows this in a neat way on their landing page, just scroll down to 'The basics'

Answer (score 0):

As **static angularjs application** will contain mainly HTML, CSS and JS files you can host your project on simple apache webserver. (Apache - http://httpd.apache.org/)

If you are making a **dynamic angularjs application** you will have webservices returning you JSON data. If you implement the restful webservices in Java (using Jersey) you can deploy you entire angularjs application with java webserivce implementation to tomcat web server. (Tomcat - http://tomcat.apache.org/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Decided to answer this old question because its one of the few that show on google when searched.

You do not need to use Grunt anymore, I do not know if this was needed at the time of this question.

instead just do

```
ng build my-app
```

this would have saved me some hours.

[link to current doc](https://angular.io/cli/build)